# How to generate a circle which has intensity slowly change in [0.5 1.5]?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I want to generate a circle which its intensities (in circle) are slowly changed in [0.5 1.5] as below figure (without boundary line). It means the data in x direction is from `0.5, 0.505, 0.51,....,1.5`(just assume, it may be non-linear changing, i.e cos or sine function as my code). I only done to create a circle in MATLAB. Could you help me to continue to finish my task?

This is my code which only was successul to generate a circle

```
rows=160;
columns=180;
circleCenterX = round(columns/2); 
circleCenterY =  round(rows/2); % square area 0f 500*500 
circleRadius1 = 50;    % big circle radius 
circle1 = false(rows, columns); 
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:columns, 1:rows); 
circle1((x - circleCenterX).^2 + (y - circleCenterY).^2 <= circleRadius1.^2) = true; 
%% Slowly changed
t1 = 0:pi/(rows.*1.2):pi/1.2;
t2 = 0:pi/(cols.*1.2):pi/1.2;
data_x=sin(t1);
data_x(end)=[];
data_y=cos(t2);
data_y(end)=[];
%% Re-scale in range [0.5 1.5]
x = data_x(:);
y = data_y(:);

alpha=0.5;
up_range=1+alpha;
down_range=1-alpha;
data_scale_x = (x - min(x)) * (up_range - down_range) / (max(x) - min(x)) + down_range;
%% Same with y
data_scale_y = (y - min(y)) * (up_range - down_range) / (max(y) - min(y)) + down_range;
%% Assign to image
[X,Y] = meshgrid(data_scale_x,data_scale_y);
image=[X];
imshow(circle1,[]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `fill` and set the appropriate properties like

```
r = 1;
center = [0 0];

% generate the circle points
num_points = 100;
t = linspace(0,2*pi,num_points);
x = r*sin(t+pi/2) + center(1);
y = r*cos(t+pi/2) + center(2);

%generate the color values
color = interp1([0 round(num_points/2) num_points],[1 0 1],1:num_points);

%plot the filled circle and set the appropriate colormap
colormap('gray')
fill(x,y,color,'EdgeColor','none')

%save with a given resolution and size
set(gca,'Visible','off');
set(gca, 'position', [0 0 1 1]);
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches');
set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0 0 160 180]);
print 'test.bmp' -dbmp -r1
```

Which results in this figure:

[image]

Comment: Thank FirefoxMetzger. nice answer, It will be rescale in [0.5 1.5] by my code. Is it possible to put your circle in to a image size 160x180 and export it to file?

Comment: @user8430 Of course you can save the circle with a given size, see above code

Comment: I mean the circle will be placed in a rectangular (as background) 160x180. It look like https://www.dropbox.com/s/k28u6n2jrxiop43/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: And when I save to image, the range did not show in [0.5 1.5]. it is integer number

Comment: @user8430 Yes, you can also plot it into an existing axes, but then you will have to calculate the correct center point and radius before (imagesc has its origin in the top left corner and measures in px not inch). I don't understand what you want. Image formats store pixel values as integers, so I'm affraid you can't 'store' an image with a pixel value of 1.5 . Could you be more specific?

Comment: May be store in .mat file?

Comment: a .mat file stores data, not a rendered graphic. I suppose you can also store the objects creating the figure or axes in a .mat file, but that will not give you indivitual values for each pixel, because those are rendered at runtime.